# Mock Component: Type Mock has no index signature

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

For some reason my MockComponent throws a linting error:

```
ERROR in src/app/helpers/mock-component.ts(17,13): error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Mock' has no index signature.
```

The code looks like this:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export function MockComponent(options: Component): Component {

    const metadata: Component = {
        selector: options.selector,
        template: options.template || '',
        inputs: options.inputs,
        outputs: options.outputs || [],
        exportAs: options.exportAs || ''
    };

    class Mock { }

    if (metadata.outputs) {
        metadata.outputs.forEach((method: any) => {
            Mock.prototype[method] = new EventEmitter<any>();
        });
    }

    return Component(metadata)(Mock as any);
}
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason: I just had to cast Mock as any in the following line:

```
(Mock as any).prototype[method] = new EventEmitter<any>();
```